# drupal hook_menu_alter() for adding tabs

Tags: drupal, menu, tabs, hook, alter

I want to add some tabs in the "node/%/edit" page from my module called "cssswitch".
When I click "Rebuild Menus", the two new tabs are displayed, but they are displayed for ALL nodes when editing them, not just for the node "cssswitch". I want these new tabs to be displayed only when editing node of type "cssswitch".

The other problem is when I clear all cache, the tabs completely dissapear from all edit pages. Below is the code I wrote.

```
    function cssswitch_menu_alter(&$items) {

        $node = menu_get_object();
        //print_r($node);
        //echo $node->type; //exit();
        if ($node->type == 'cssswitch') {

            $items['node/%/edit/schedulenew'] = array(
                'title' => 'Schedule1',
                'access callback'=>'user_access',
                'access arguments'=>array('view cssswitch'),
                'page callback' => 'cssswitch_schedule',
                'page arguments' => array(1),
                'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
                'weight'=>4,
            );

            $items['node/%/edit/schedulenew2'] = array(
                'title' => 'Schedule2',
                'access callback'=>'user_access',
                'access arguments'=>array('view cssswitch'),
                'page callback' => 'cssswitch_test2',
                'page arguments' => array(1),
                'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
                'weight'=>3,
            );  


        }

    }

function cssswitch_test(){
    return 'test';
}

function cssswitch_test2(){
    return 'test2';
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hook_menu_alter() is only called during the menu building process, so you can't do dynamic node type checks within that function.

However, to achieve what you want, you can do this with a custom access callback as follows:

```
       // Note, I replaced the '%' in your original code with '%node'. See hook_menu() for details on this.
       $items['node/%node/edit/schedulenew2'] = array(
            ...
            'access callback'=>'cssswitch_schedulenew_access',
            // This passes in the $node object as the argument.
            'access arguments'=>array(1),
            ...
        );
```

Then, in your new custom access callback:

```
function cssswitch_schedulenew_access($node) {
  // Check that node is the proper type, and that the user has the proper permission.
  return $node->type == 'cssswitch' && user_access('view cssswitch');
}
```

For other node types, this function will return false, thus denying access, and thus removing the tab.

Comment: +1 - just one additional note: `hook_menu_alter()` is supposed to be used for altering menu entries provided by other modules. As the OP wants to add new entries, he should just use `hook_menu()` instead.